# Animate Bar programmatically

Tags: javascript, css

I would like a bar to animate from left to right. I have a numerical input. After the submit click, the bar should then be animated.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to trigger the animation. I deliberately set the initial width value to 150px to show that the animation actually works, but it not works if be triggered programmatically.

```js
btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const val = document.querySelector('input').value
  draw(val);
})

function draw(val) {
  bar = document.getElementById("bar");  
  bar.style.setProperty('--width', (val * 10) + "px");  
}
```

```css
:root {
  --width: 150px;
}
#bar{
  background:red;
  height:50px;
  margin:50px;
  transform-origin:top;  
  animation: grow 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes grow {
  from {
    width:0px;
  }
  to {
    width:var(--width);
  }
}
```

```html
<input value="5">
<button id="btn">draw</button>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of animation, use CSS `transtion`. Then (almost) any change to an element would be animated.

```js
const runIt = () => {
  $('.bar').css('width', '100%');
};
```

```css
.bar {
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: blue;
  transition: 2s;
  width: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bar"></div>
<button onclick="runIt()">Run</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect use for [CSS Transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). Rather than adding an animation to the element, just set its width to have a `transition` time. Then, any time you change the width, it will be animated.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const val = document.querySelector('input').value
  draw(val);
})

function draw(val) {
  bar = document.getElementById("bar");  
  bar.style.setProperty('width', (val * 10) + "px");  
}
```

```css
#bar{
  background:red;
  width: 0;
  height:50px;
  margin:50px;
  transform-origin:top;  
  transition: width 2s; /* Any time the width changes, it will be animated of 2 seconds */
}
```

```html
<input value="5">
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Comment: Merci! transition ist realy the solution for this case..  